# Delete row by condition check in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have similar data as I have shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to delete rows containing similar date containing greater time mentioned in column E for the same date using VBA. For example user data is available for different time on same date. but I want to keep row having minimum time than others.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Which version of Office are you using?  Office 365 has the `MINIFS` / `MAXIFS` functions, which would simplify this greatly.